# I want to input Random data generated inside "start-job" to global array variable "Data" but under error has occurred

Tags: powershell

I want to input Random data generated inside "start-job" to global array variable "Data"
but error has occurred

i'm using powershell
the under is my powershell code

=========================

```
$global:Data = @()
Start-Job -ScriptBlock{
    $test = get-random
    $using:Data += $test
}
```

=========================

error : The assignment expression is not valid. The input to an assignment operator must be an object that is able to accept assignments, such as a variable or a property.